# File system type and mount options for Archlinux on NVMe SSD drive

Tags: filesystems, ssd

I know that there are many articles and wiki available for this matter, and I have read many of them already. But I'm still confused also because some of them are probably outdated. So maybe I can clarify some doubts here...

I want to install Archlinux (which is a rolling distro, so latest kernel, latest drivers, latest everything) on my new Dell XPS 13 laptop equipped with a NVMe CX2-8B512-Q11 NV SSD drive alongside Windows 10.
I've already shrunk windows partition, disabled fastboot and secure boot etc.

The question is now about which file system to choose for `/`. I've read some articles and I learned that:

- BTRFS is cool but still unstable. I read of people being screwed up using it. So it's not recommended at this stage.
- EXT4 is the most reliable one today and the only down side is jounaling with takes space on the drive.
- F2FS is designed for SSD but still tricky at this time to get it running.

So the best choice for a stable system as of today is EXT4, right?

About mount options: DISCARD seems to be deprecated an not recommend. Arch wiki advise to enable periodic trim service. Are there other mount options to add to fstab (e.g rw,relatime,data=ordered)?

Comment: "F2FS [...] tricky at this time to get it running." If you are referring to the comment regarding GRUB and F2FS on the Arch Wiki site: I wouldn't recommend using GRUB with an EFI system anyway. Use systemd-boot instead. On the other hand, if you compare the reliability of F2FS and Btrfs, please consider that F2FS is much younger (2013) than Btrfs (2009). Btrfs may not be the most popular Linux file system out there, but it has been used "in production" for quite some time already, which probably cannot be said about F2FS. Ext4 is probably your best choice, as you said yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two NVMe drives in my Lenovo P50 running Arch, no issues so far, running ext4.

I have fstrim.timer enabled instead of using the discard option in fstab.

> sudo systemctl enable fstrim.timer

The only other notable option is:

> noatime

You'll want to get rid of:

1. relatime
2. diratime